# How to create multiplication tables using C++ using nested for loops

Tags: c++, codeblocks, multiplication

I'm trying to create a [Multiplication Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIMAf.png) like this one but I'm having issues with the spacing. Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong. I got the program to work without trying to create a table but every time I attempt to create tables it goes horribly wrong. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=2; i <=9; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(9) << i << "   ";
    }
    for(j = 1; j<=9; j++)
    {
        cout << setw (9) << (i*j) << "    ";
    }

    printf("%d x %d = %d\n", i, j, i*j);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably should show your output.

Comment: You have two loops, but they aren't nested.

Comment: You should provide the expected output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops. You can use the `'\t'` special character to insert horizontal tabs but this may not work well if you decide to make a bigger table later on. and the Here is a solution for your expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (i = 2 + 4*k; i < 6 + 4*k; i++)
            {
                cout << i << " x " << j << " = " << i * j << '\t';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
2 x 1 = 2       3 x 1 = 3       4 x 1 = 4       5 x 1 = 5
2 x 2 = 4       3 x 2 = 6       4 x 2 = 8       5 x 2 = 10
2 x 3 = 6       3 x 3 = 9       4 x 3 = 12      5 x 3 = 15
2 x 4 = 8       3 x 4 = 12      4 x 4 = 16      5 x 4 = 20
2 x 5 = 10      3 x 5 = 15      4 x 5 = 20      5 x 5 = 25
2 x 6 = 12      3 x 6 = 18      4 x 6 = 24      5 x 6 = 30
2 x 7 = 14      3 x 7 = 21      4 x 7 = 28      5 x 7 = 35
2 x 8 = 16      3 x 8 = 24      4 x 8 = 32      5 x 8 = 40
2 x 9 = 18      3 x 9 = 27      4 x 9 = 36      5 x 9 = 45

6 x 1 = 6       7 x 1 = 7       8 x 1 = 8       9 x 1 = 9
6 x 2 = 12      7 x 2 = 14      8 x 2 = 16      9 x 2 = 18
6 x 3 = 18      7 x 3 = 21      8 x 3 = 24      9 x 3 = 27
6 x 4 = 24      7 x 4 = 28      8 x 4 = 32      9 x 4 = 36
6 x 5 = 30      7 x 5 = 35      8 x 5 = 40      9 x 5 = 45
6 x 6 = 36      7 x 6 = 42      8 x 6 = 48      9 x 6 = 54
6 x 7 = 42      7 x 7 = 49      8 x 7 = 56      9 x 7 = 63
6 x 8 = 48      7 x 8 = 56      8 x 8 = 64      9 x 8 = 72
6 x 9 = 54      7 x 9 = 63      8 x 9 = 72      9 x 9 = 81
```